# List column not being shown in crawled properties in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

HI

I have a column named "Grade" of type "Number" in a List in some site. I have made a Full Crawl as well as an Incremental Crawl, but the Column is not appearing in the crawled properties.

I want to create a Managed Property out of this Grade, but when I click on "Add Mapping" the I don't see the Grade crawled property.

Does all columns of a list are crawled or not ?

Please tell me if something is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing SharePoint creates crawl property for all site columns so what you have to is due to some reasons the internal name of your column has been changed you have to find the internal column name and try to find the crawl property by that name you will be able to find it in crawl properties

Comment: I concur, this is likely the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but this was not the issue, actually while creating a metadata property, I was selecting a datatype which was not compatible with the Crawled Property's data type, so it was not showing up in the dialog.